# Слайдер по клику на кнопке в модальном окне на html и css

Tags: html, css

Привет всем!

Нашел классный слайдер на *CSS*. Попытался сделать, чтобы его можно было вызывать в модальном окне кликом по кнопке... в модальном окне поверх основной страницы его разместить не сложно, но не уверен, что можно такую конструкцию вызвать и скрыть кликом по ссылке на чистом *CSS* и *HTML*. Проффи, подскажите, можно ли вообще так сделать?

Вот сам слайдер:

```css
/* CSS Document */

#slider {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

#slides {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #333, inset 1px 1px 0 #ddd;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.inner {
  width: 500%;
}

.inner:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
}

.page {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
}

.page img {
  width: 588px;
  height: 250px;
}

#overflow {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#slider input {
  display: none;
}

#controls {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 120px;
  left: 0;
  height: 50px;
}

#controls label {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0.3;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#controls label:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}


/* перелистывание фотографий */

#slide1:checked~#controls label:nth-child(2),
#slide2:checked~#controls label:nth-child(3),
#slide3:checked~#controls label:nth-child(4),
#slide4:checked~#controls label:nth-child(5),
#slide5:checked~#controls label:nth-child(1) {
  /* первые пять значений создадут стрелку справа*/
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-left: 20px solid #333;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  float: right;
  margin-right: -30px;
  /* за блок*/
  display: block;
}

#slide1:checked~#controls label:nth-child(5),
#slide2:checked~#controls label:nth-child(1),
#slide3:checked~#controls label:nth-child(2),
#slide4:checked~#controls label:nth-child(3),
#slide5:checked~#controls label:nth-child(4) {
  /*стрелка слева*/
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-left: -30px;
}

#slide1:checked~#slides .inner {
  margin-left: 0;
}

#slide2:checked~#slides .inner {
  margin-left: -100%;
}

#slide3:checked~#slides .inner {
  margin-left: -200%;
}

#slide4:checked~#slides .inner {
  margin-left: -300%;
}

#slide5:checked~#slides .inner {
  margin-left: -400%;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide1" checked="">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide2">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide3">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide4">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide5">

  <div id="slides">
    <div id="overflow">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="page">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/588x250" />
        </div>
        <div class="page">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/588x250" />
        </div>
        <div class="page">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/588x250" />
        </div>
        <div class="page">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/588x250" />
        </div>
        <div class="page">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/588x250" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--inner-->
    </div>
    <!--overflow-->
  </div>
  <!--slides-->

  <div id="controls">
    <label for="slide1"></label>
    <label for="slide2"></label>
    <label for="slide3"></label>
    <label for="slide4"></label>
    <label for="slide5"></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Код слайдера взяли в одном месте, здесь надеетесь получить код вставки в окно. Сами-то вы что сделали?

Comment: Немного не понял вас... Вы правы этот код я взял и подкорректировал под себя... я не так давно начал изучать HTML и CSS... и продолжаю изучать, разбирая такие вещи...